# Plotting Centroid @ each Iteration

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a scenario in which i generate a matrix **C** at every iteration. The **C** matrix dimension is 2 x n. Each column in the **C** matrix is a 2-dimensional centroid and we have **n** centroid in the **C** matrix.

Since **C** matrix is updated @ every iteration, centroids are updated. I would like to plot movement of centroid 1 (which is column1). The plot should indicate me the movement of centroid 1 from previous iteration to the current iteration by drawing an arrow between the points.

I was trying to use scatter function in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
%# matrix of centroids
n = 5;
C = rand(2,n);

%# set up graphic objects
hScatter = gscatter(C(1,:), C(2,:), 1:n, [], [], 30); hold on
hQuiver = quiver(nan,nan,nan,nan);
set(hQuiver, 'AutoScale','off', 'Color','k')
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
drawnow, pause(1)

%# update and show C each iteration
for i=1:10
    %# update centroids
    oldC = C;
    C = C + randn(size(C));

    %# update centroids to new locations
    set(hScatter, {'XData'},num2cell(C(1,:))', {'YData'},num2cell(C(2,:))')

    %# plot arrow showing movement from old to new locations
    set(hQuiver, 'XData',oldC(1,:), 'YData',oldC(2,:), ...
        'UData',C(1,:)-oldC(1,:), 'VData',C(2,:)-oldC(2,:))

    %# show iteration number
    title( sprintf('Iteration %d',i) )

    %# refresh plot
    drawnow, pause(1)
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [arrow function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278) and use something like plot();hold on;

```
plot();hold on;
for i=1:iter
   arrow(C(old_iter),C(new_iter));
end;
hold off;
```